# How to deploy an update to an already released Google Workspace Addon?

Tags: testing, google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on

I have a functioning Google Sheets Add-on that is listed in the Google Workspace Marketplace. I've made changes in the new Apps Script Editor and tested them locally, now I want to push them to my users.

The process as I understand it, to press "New Deployment"

[image: screenshot of deploy button]

add a description and press "deploy"

[image: screenshot of new deployment menu]

after which I copy the "Deployment ID" into the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK page,

[image]

and hit SAVE in the bottom.
It's been a few hours and I still cannot see it being live.
Is there a review process for updates like this? Or am I missing a step?
The previous version is still being served to users as far as I can tell.

- Update in response to the comment from @ziganotschka

I am making a Google Sheets Editor Addon, and I'm only now understanding the difference between that and the Google Workspace Addon. I've resubmitted my store listing for review with Google Workspace Addon disabled, and removed the "Common" part of my manifest. I've updated the "version" number to correspond to the latest deployment.

Is it not possible to test a Sheets Editor Addon from the new editor without deploying it as a Workspace Addon? And should updating the version number be sufficient to roll out an update?

Comment: Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/update-published-add-on

Comment: Is it a Google Sheets Editor Addon or a Google Workspace Addon for Google Sheets? This is imortant to know when it comes to deployment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/types

Comment: I am only now figuring out the difference. It is a Google Sheets Editor Addon, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

From the question

> Is it not possible to test a Sheets Editor Addon from the new editor without deploying it as a Workspace Addon?

It depends on what kind of test do you want to do, if your Apps Script project is bounded or a standalone project and what do you Editor add-on does and how it does that.

I.E. you might test a simple edit trigger (onEdit) by using a function for mocking the edit event object and passing it to the onEdit function. To be clear this doesn't need to create a new version and for testing and add-on it's not necessary to make a new deployment.

> And should updating the version number be sufficient to roll out an update?

It depends on if the Cloud project OAuth consent screen was set for external use or for internal use, in the new version requires new scopes.

Let say that you fixed typo on a variable name, in this case only creating a new version and adding the version number to the add-on configuration page will be enough, but if you added a sensitive API and you add-on is set for external use, then you will have to update the OAuth consent screen and wait for Google review and approval.

Comment: my addon uses a sidebar where you can drop pdf's that get uploaded to drive with a hyperlink placed into the sheet. That only makes sense to test in context of an entire sheet, and I can only test that through the legacy editor it seems.

Comment: and assuming that the addon has worked, been reviewed, and no new scopes are added, would changing the version number and hitting "save" be sufficient to update it? And is it right that it takes several days to roll out?

Comment: Run > Test as add-on is only available on the old editor. (Ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons) but that is not the only way to test an editor add-on. If you need further details please post a new question including a brief description of your search efforts. Regarding the second comment,  the first part is already included in the answer, the answer to the second part is no. What is your source that lead you to think that it will take several days?